# Quantum Cascade Laser

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, laser, semiconductor-physics, quantum-optics

I want to learn about [quantum cascade laser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cascade_laser) in a six month time. Can anyone please suggest me any reading materials or video lectures. I have background in calculus and linear algebra. I am learning quantum mechanics now.

Comment: I close this question (v2) as _off-topic_ because book recommendation questions fit poorly to the Q&A format of Phys.SE. In general Phys.SE only allows a limited number of book recommendation questions. For more information, see various meta posts, e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4697/2451).

Answer (score 0):

The book: "Quantum Cascade Lasers" by Prof. Jérôme Faist

Comment: This is okay because the question iis only looking for a book, but it would be nice if you could explain what's good about the book, etc.